# Solo-Parachain-Bridge POC is not working

Tags: bridge, parity-bridges-common

I'm trying to run the following repo, but it's not working.

https://github.com/paritytech/solo-para-bridge-poc

```bash
$ make build-all

cargo b -r -p rialto-parachain-collator && \
cargo b -r -p millau-bridge-node && \
cargo b -r -p rialto-bridge-node && \
cargo build -r -p substrate-relay
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech//polkadot`
error: failed to load source for dependency `kusama-runtime`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech//polkadot?branch=locked-for-gav                                                               -xcm-v3-and-bridges#9fc6b88c

Caused by:
  object not found - no match for id (9fc6b88ccc7abc1418ff5260e8cc492e647306a0);                                                                class=Odb (9); code=NotFound (-3)
make: *** [Makefile:3: build-all] Error 101
```

Can someone help me figure out the issue?

Comment: It depends on a deleted git branch `gav-xcm-v3`. I suggest opening an issue in the repository.

Comment: Yes, it is because of the deleted dependent git branch.
I'm working on it. 
@cuteolaf I'll update you once done.

Comment: Issues are not enabled for this repo.
https://github.com/paritytech/solo-para-bridge-poc

Comment: @PawanBisht 
Please let me know if I can pair with you to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @cuteolaf, it is building for me, but let me make it up to date with the latest polkadot version. Then we'll look if your issue persists or not.

Comment: Did you try to build it after `cargo clean`? I think it might not work.

Comment: @cuteolaf, while I'm working on it. I'd suggest you use the same Cargo.lock file for building your project.
Here is my telegram:@pawanbisht62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, the project was using a specific branch for XCMv3 support, that's why it was throwing errors.
Now the project has been updated with the official XCMv3 release.

*Note*: You have to use the same Cargo.lock which is present in the project.